# HTML5 audio/video stop buffer

Tags: html, audio, buffer

Is there a way to stop buffering in the browsers.

I have an audio tag which is pointing to some mp3 file.

Browsers starts buffering the audio while it is playing.

Can I stop the buffering ?

I know ideally if you have audio data coming in faster then what the client can play why not buffer it.

What I am asking is audio player should only buffer the min amount and ask for more data.

I know it is a get request so it is not really a protocol to ask more. So just consume a chunk, play it and consume more.

Any ideas. Maybe 206 and seeking functionality to request more.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this option in your tag:

```
<audio preload='none'>
```

This option avoids pre-buffering, so it should solve your problem