# Chrome HTML5 Video Buffering

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, buffer

I am using video.js to show video content. I have a program that handles the streaming requests so the source of the video tag is set to a program which serves up the requested bytes.

The issue is that Chrome is requesting the entire video, range header on the GET request:
Range:bytes=0-

What I need to happen is that Chrome requests the minimum amount of bytes in order to start playback. I understand that this could lead to a lag due to the high number of requests being made, but it's what I need :(

Does anyone know how I could limit the buffer Chrome uses for this element?
There is a similar question here: [HTML5 audio/video stop buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804631/html5-audio-video-stop-buffer)

I've tried setting preload to none. This works in that it prevents the initial buffering from taking place, before the user has click play. But once it starts, it requests the entire range :(((

Many thanks,
Arvy

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The 206 Partial Content can be responded to with however many bytes you need to supply. The client (Chrome in my case) asks for more anyways as it didn't receive a full range the first time.

For example, here is the request header `Range:bytes=1000048-` This means that the client has requested the rest of the file starting at byte 1000048. The program does not need to respond with the full range, in my case I am returning only 500000 bytes, so I take the 1000048 and add 499999 to get the end byte and format the headers accordingly. Seems to work fine. Hope it helps someone.